# Using create-react-app as a non root user, is this possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, create-react-app

When I try to execute `npx create-react-app client` the result is always:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /media/veracrypt1/Mega/Dev/JOBIFY/client/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/media/veracrypt1/Mega/Dev/JOBIFY/client/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/media/veracrypt1/Mega/Dev/JOBIFY/client/node_modules/.bin/parser'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/media/veracrypt1/Mega/Dev/JOBIFY/client/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shmue/.npm/_logs/2022-08-11T13_45_19_897Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
```

This is because I am not root.

It is essential that I can complete this action as the non root user.

After 20 minutes of googling I am yet to find my solution.

I am using Ubuntu 20.

Please assist me.

Many thanks, :-)

Samuel

---

### PS: I have already chowned the user's .npm file to this user.

As per one of the answers, I updated the users .bashrc file:

[Click to view my user's .bashrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESvde.png)

Sadly the issue is not resolved!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this operation in one of your system drivers

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this inside your .bashrc, and log off and log in

```
# this alowing installing node dependencies without root
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export npm_config_prefix="$HOME/.local"
```

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Node.js

Comment: Sadly the output is the same:

Comment: 'relog' means log off and in, again?

Comment: User .bashrc, or root .bashrc? I added both and have the same output :( ... Help please

Comment: Thanks edited, yes log off and in again.

Comment: user .bashrc, /home/user/.bashrc

Comment: Please see updated question. Sadly it did not resolve the issue, but thank you for your efforts